# Umlaut in Java SAX Parser

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing, sax

I am currently having trouble with German umlaut values in a XML document I received.

It displays / saves the value as a "**Ã¼**" instead of a "**ü**".

The XML Encoding is set to **UTF-8** which should be capable of displaying umlauts.

Also I couldn't find any option to set a locale on the SAX parser.

Is there any other way I can make the values save correctly?

btw: I am using eclipse as IDE.

All help is very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is encoded in UTF-8, but you are decoding it with ISO-8859-1.

Try to use `InputStream` and other "binary"-oriented APIs for XML. Avoid using a `Reader`, or trying to convert from `byte[]` to a `String` before parsing XML. You are much more likely to mess up the character encoding than the parser is.

Comment: Yeap, using a InputStream instead of a Reader worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for this fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Setting XML encoding to UTF-8 in XML declaration is the one thing but another thing is the physical encoding of the XML document i.e., you can have a XML file that says `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but the file itself might still be ANSI encoded (or whatever).

Comment: That would be malformed XML. The XML is fine in this case. The code reading it is wrong.